# Add text between divs that are on the left and right side of a div

Tags: css, html

[Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qgpm3r81/1/)

HTML

```
<div class = "container">
    Text Here = <div class = "plus">+</div> Text Also Here <div class = "minus">-</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
.plus {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    text-align: center;
}
.minus {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I want to format my text with some divs in between, something along the lines of this

Text  Text

However, when I try to make this work it ends up as

text
(Plus Div)
Text
(Minus Div)

which is not what I want.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qgpm3r81/4/

Comment: @Michael_B this is really really close to what I want. It's laid out exactly how I want this to be just too spaced out due to using flex and space-around. I want to be able to do this with a single space after the =, the +, and before the -. If I can't figure this out, your method will work fine with a bit of tweaking to my layout. Thanks!

Comment: Here's the revised fiddle. It's aligned left. If you want everything centered, change `justify-contents` value to `center`. http://jsfiddle.net/qgpm3r81/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div>Text Here =</div>
    <div class="plus">+</div>
    <div>Text Also Here</div>
    <div class="minus">-</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;    
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
}

.container > div {
    margin: 5px;    
}

.plus {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    text-align: center;
}
.minus {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qgpm3r81/5/

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I never really understood flex but this helped a lot in more than one way. It solved my problem, and added some useful ammo to my repertoire. Thanks!

Comment: This article has some good info on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Use `span` instead of `div` like this:

```
<div class = "container">
    Text Here = <span class = "plus">+</span> Text Also Here <span class = "minus">-</span>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/qgpm3r81/3/

Comment: I want to use this method but it does not work with the width from css. I'd prefer the + and - divs to be 20x20 not following how large the text itself is. Your method is almost what I want but not quite what I need. Thanks!